# Unit testing repository. Why is DBContext returning bad values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, caching, dbcontext

I am unit testing ASP MVC aplication. Now I am testing a repository. I have table in database with atributes ID( primary key int ),  ItemName ( varchar ), IsValid ( bit - true/false ).
In the repository, there are methods like Create, Update, Delete  which I am testing with unit tests (The tests work with atribute isValid). There is also method getAllItems

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetAllItems()
{
return _db.ItemSet.Where(w => w.isValid);
}
```

After running unit tests of Create, Update, Delete there is one more Unit test method which test getAllWorkitem method.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void GetAllItems_Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var allWorkitems = _ws.GetAllItems();
        //Act

        //Assert
        foreach (Item currentItem in allItems)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(true, currentItem.Valid);
        }

    }
```

If I run all tests separately, it works ok. If I run all test together, there is a problem.
In the var allWorkitems there are Items which have isValid = false and isValid = true.

I think dbContext is caching queries and data for higher speed of testing. Are there any posibitilies that will disable this chaching. Or is there any other problem?

Comment: Are you sharing the `_ws` object between all your tests?

Comment: Yes I do and one dbContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before each unit test executes, you must set the context of the tests to a clean state. By that I mean you need to clear any data that a previous test may have created, clearing the path for the next test.

One way to do that is by using a test setup method e.g.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    // This function will be executed before each test.
    // Use this function as an opportunity to clear any shared objects e.g.
    // dbContext <- Delete all data that is not required.
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    // Arrange.
    // Add 1 item to the dbContext

    // Act
    var actual = _ws.GetAllItems();

    // Assert.
    Assert.AreEqual(1, actual.Count());
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test2()
{
    // Arrange.
    // Here, the dbContext will have been cleared in the Setup() function.
    // Add 5 items to the dbContext

    // Act
    var actual = _ws.GetAllItems();

    // Assert.
    Assert.AreEqual(5, actual.Count()); // Total items should be 5, not 6.
}
```

All of the above code is hypothetical, I made it up on the fly. However it does illustrate my point that you need to configure each unit test to be in an expected state before executing them.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, your setup method could look like this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    _db = new MyIContainer();
    _ws = new ItemService(_db);
}
```

That way, each test will be working with fresh objects and no lingering data from previous tests.

Comment: That sounds perfect. So what should I do in setup? I have private static MyIContainer _db = new MyIContainer(); and IItemService _ws = new ItemService(_db); Should I inicializate it again in the method with annotation [TestInitialize]?